# Asp.net core attribute route issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, attributerouting

I have this code:

```
[Route("Users")]
public class UserRegistrationController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet("details/{userId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails(Guid userId)
    {
        // .....
    }

    [HttpPost("Save")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUser(UserVM userVM)
    {
        // ......
        return RedirectToAction("details", "Users", new { userId = userVM.UserId });
    }
}
```

If I save the user redirectToAction generate userId as query string, this create an issue.

I mean instead of

```
https://localhost:5001/Users/Details/5de304c7-4c69-4819-c879-08d90306b555
```

redirect to action creates the URL as

```
https://localhost:5001/Users/Details?userId=5de304c7-4c69-4819-c879-08d90306b555
```

which causes a 404 error.

How do I solve this issue? I want to pass userId in route as below

```
https://localhost:5001/Users/Details/5de304c7-4c69-4819-c879-08d90306b555
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is type of `userVM.UserId`? If it is `string` then try like `return RedirectToAction("details", "Users", new { userId = new Guid(userVM.UserId) });`.

Comment: @Karan userVM.UserId is already GUID so no need to create Guid again. Sorry this one not work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, the action method UserDetails  need to add route **[Route("details")]** This will solve the issue.

```
[Route("Users")]
public class UserRegistrationController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet("details/{userId}")]
    [Route("details")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails(Guid userId)
    {
        // .....
    }

    [HttpPost("Save")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUser(UserVM userVM)
    {
        // ......
        return RedirectToAction("details", "Users", new { userId = userVM.UserId });
    }
}
```